# Need to get server hostname on which my PHP app is deployed/running

Tags: php, hostname

These are the things I have tried :

1. `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] : sub..amazinglocal.com`
2. `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] : amazinglocal.com`
3. `php_uname('n') : sub..amazinglocal.com`
4. `gethostbyname()`

I need the kind of name that is the output of command `hostname` on the server.

Example : `appmysql.staging.la3.do.amazing.com`

Comment: Doesn't sound like you've set the OS / webserver up with the hostnames you're expecting?

Comment: I ran `hostname` command on my server and getting the correct name. But the above php methods are not giving me this name of the server.

Comment: You could always call `hostname` from your PHP using `exec` or similar. That would guarantee you'd get the same value. I would kind of have expected 3 and 4 to have worked. What did they give you?

Comment: gethostname() is giving my OS name and php_uname('n') is giving me `sub..amazinglocal.com`

Answer (score 1):

Okay so I've tried a couple of more options and this one works the best : [gethostname()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gethostname.php)

`gethostname() : vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64`

On  the server, it'll throw an ouput like :

`mysqlapp1.prod.do.superawesomeserver.com`